# How to install kernel from 12.10 into 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, 12.10

I would like to install the current kernel that is in Quantal Quetzel into another distribution I have of Precise Pangolin? If you are wanting to know why this is, its because the current Quantal kernel supports my Sandy Bridge chipset best, and it also is working great even as its in the Alpha stage, on my laptop.

So I want to install it into my Kubuntu 12.04. What is the best method to do this? Should I compile from Ubuntu source directly, or is it possible somehow to just add a quantal repository to Precise and have apt download and install the current quantal kernel and headers for me?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually the 12.10 kernels will be made available as backports to 12.04. However this hasn't happened yet.

However you can help test the 12.10 kernels on 12.04 by checking out the following test case:

- http://packages.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/223/builds

and click on the "Quantal kernel for precise LTS" link and follow those instructions. There are also links on there on how to report bugs for these questions. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Why not use this: https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/kernel/+packages or this: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ instead?